# Flashing Screen

Tags: screen

I have just installed 12.10.
Problem is the screen keeps flashing. Maybe something to do with the video card? Very annoying as I can hardly see what I am typing here! Any ideas as to what I must do to correct this?

Comment: Try booting into [Recovery Mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).

Comment: I get that occasionally with my ATI card, I have to turn the computer off so the card totally resets. A reboot doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just spent many hours with Ubuntu 13.04 and video probs ... I found this [handy tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/display) (my card is Nvidia).

Answer (score 0):

I installed ubuntu 13.04 on a ThinkPad T43 . The screen started flashing on login. Changing the desktop background stopped it.